# Generating GWT MVP skeleton in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, mvp

Ok this may sound stupid because I know that I can just create files manually and put code in them. But what is the quicker way to generate ready to use MVP (Model-View-Presenter) skeleton package in Eclipse directly? I have seen someone doing it but don't remember how.

Something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It's in `File -> New -> Other -> GWTP -> GWTP Presenter`.